# Context Canceled when using Go with BigQuery

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-go-client

I am trying to insert a record to biqquery & here the code which does the insert.

```
func (s *Storage) Insert(w *warehouse.WarehouseRecord) error {
   event, err := w.Marshal()
   if err != nil {
      return err
   }
   logger.Info("inserting record to big query")
   ins := s.client.Dataset(s.dataSet).Table(event.GetTableName()).Inserter()
   ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
   defer cancel()
   if err := ins.Put(ctx, event); err != nil {
      return err
   }
   return nil
}
```

When i run my application, the insert fails with error. The error says `context canceled`, but I am not canceling the context from parent, I suspect its happening inside the client package. Have any one of you come across this error?

```
Post "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/dinesh-dev/datasets/analytics_test/tables/agent/insertAll?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": context canceled{"error":"Post \"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/dinesh-dev/datasets/analytics_test/tables/agent/insertAll?alt=json\u0026prettyPrint=false\": context canceled"
```

Comment: How long does it take until it's canceled?

Comment: Is `ins.Put` blocking? If not, then the context is canceled by the `defer` when your method returns

Comment: Put is blocking, I even tried with`context.Background()` same result.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the logs in the bigquery side? it should be in Stackdriver. Just to see if your code is reaching google cloud, or it just fails before.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution? @DineshGowda

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `context` you've given on initialisation of `foo.NewClient(ctx, ...)` is canceled. This context should not be canceled, see [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go#hdr-Timeouts_and_Cancellation):

> // Do not cancel the context passed to NewClient: dialing happens asynchronously
> and the context is used to refresh credentials in the background.